# How do I point example.com to example.appspot.com?

Tags: dns, hosting, web-hosting, google-compute-engine

I'm using Google Compute Engine and want to point a custom url to the appspot domain. I don't need a whole hosting service, so I was wondering if there was a company that would allow me to purchase/transfer/register a domain, and host it simply pointing it to the appspot domain. I know I can do this through godaddy and cloudflare, but I don't want to pay for a bunch of stuff I'm not using. Is there any company that could just purchase and point the domain for me for really cheap?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if you're using App Engine (appspot.com) or Compute Engine. (no DNS by default, just raw IP addresses)

In any case, you'll need to register the domain with a domain registrar like GoDaddy.  It looks like Google's option, Google Domains, [is currently an invite-only beta](http://domains.google.com/).

Once you've registered your domain name, the process is a little different depending on whether you meant App Engine or Compute Engine.

- For App Engine, you'll want to set up [DNS A records for the domain itself (aka "named domain" forwarding)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#naked_domain).  This can be done in the Google Developer Console.
- For Compute Engine, you'll probably want to set the A record for the named domain to point to a static IP address you have reserved in your GCE project.  You can assign a static address to either a single instance (for small websites) or to a [load balancer](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/).  If I were setting this up for a company, I would probably try to use the [HTTP load balancing feature that's in limited preview](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cross-region-example), as it can perform latency-optimized cross-region load balancing.